# PHP Session Retrieve data and use it on other page

Tags: php, session

I want to store information other that the `$_POST` (like for username and password), what I also want to know is how would I get other information like their address to be stored in the session?
I then want to display that information on a separate page.

Any help would be appreciated if you need more information just ask.

Comment: Store the address on a database and keep only the ID of it on a session and on the next page, read the ID from database to retrieve the address.

Comment: you got an example please?

Comment: Show some efforts on what you've done and tried and perhaps I will get you an example ;). [Here is a good stat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and [selecting it from database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: This => http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/ will surely get you started.

Comment: ok, ill have a go then thanks

Comment: [Here is a good stat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and [selecting it from database](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)